# angular directive for isotope layout

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, jquery-isotope, angular-directive

I am new to angular, started exploring the custom directives, I was trying to create a custom directive for applying isotope layout once the ng-repeat completes the loading

here is following code snippet

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


app.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      if (scope.$last === true) {
        $timeout(function() {
          scope.$emit(
            $('.grid2').isotope({
              layoutMode: 'masonry',
              animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false,
              }
            })
          );
        });
      }
    }
  }
});

app.controller('userNames', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("apicall").success(function(response) {
    $scope.names = response.response;
  });
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="userNames">
  <div class="grid2" my-directive ng-repeat="x in names">
    <div class="box"><span>{{ x.username }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the code is not working please help in fixing this.

Comment: Did you find a solution?